# my ETH stuck in "internal transaction"

Tags: internal-transactions

I withdrew .22370372 eth from bitstamp to my ledger wallet and the transaction is appearing in "internal transaction". My address is: `0x3088C856fc2DF62839bA8E81d81026D3a36c01a5`

What can I do to have these funds appear in my wallet? They have never made it to my wallet. Need immediate assistance please!
[image]

Comment: I have same problem. Etherscan helpdesk does not reply for weeks. Can someone help please? https://etherscan.io/address/0x5095b75e6433398d43e72b0ad5e711d41848c5bd

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the ether transfer shows up in "internal transactions" just means it was part of a smart contract transaction. It has no bearing on whether the ether got transferred or not.

The app you're using to view your balance probably just doesn't understand this type of transaction. https://etherscan.io/address/0x3088C856fc2DF62839bA8E81d81026D3a36c01a5 may be a more helpful view. The numbers there appear to add up (including the ether in the "internal transactions" tab).